# Layout design over navigation action bar

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I am looking for a solution to design an element on the top of the navigation action bar and also a way to increase the size of the action bar. One way I can think of, is to disable the navigation action bar and then design. Is there any way if it's achievable without disabling the action bar?

Here is the design template:
[image]

just to be clear i am looking for an idea to design `connect` tab where one half is on the navigation action bar while other is on scroll view

```
xml for main 

        <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:background="#696969">
    
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />
    
            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
                android:background="#696969">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp">
                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Filter"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:textSize="26sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        >
    
                    </Button>
                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="scan"
                        android:textSize="26sp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        >
    
                    </Button>
                </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>
    
        </RelativeLayout>
    
    
    
    
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


here is xml for toolbar

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@drawable/backkground">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        app:cardElevation="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@color/black">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_cast_connected_24">

            </ImageView>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:text="Connected"
                android:textSize="44sp">

            </TextView>
        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>



</RelativeLayout>
```

I am afraid i can show all the codes as its proprietry but i just wrote some to mitigate my current solution by dividing the background colo.lol.

Comment: use margin in minus `-` from top means marginTop="-100dp"

Comment: tried that but view gets truncated. even used setZ value to get upper on the action bar but doesn't seems to be working....

Comment: ok show me XML code. Add XML code to your question or use the `Appbar` widget to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After hard work of 30min. I got your answer. In your image, `Toolbar` is already in use with `backButton, refreshButton, BluetothButton, and locationButton` and they created the `Connect` button in `TabLayout` that's why it shows half on `TabLayout` and half on `Blank Spaces`.

I created it as shown in the template.

This is my XML layout code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!--    Your ToolBar Code or Other Code-->
    
    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/myTooBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_height="?actionBarSize">
<!--    Here is sample textView with color-->
        <TextView
            android:background="@color/purple_500"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </TableLayout>
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
        app:cardElevation="10dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/myTooBar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="@string/connect"
        android:textColor="@color/gray"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:drawableLeftCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_cell_wifi_24"
        app:drawableTint="@color/gray" />
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    
<!--    Your more code of Activity-->
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and this is the result

[image]

I hope it'll help you.

**EDIT -1: Added more radius to `cardView`**